# Can not start Certbot container in Laradock Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, certbot, laradock

When use start certbot container in Docker, the result is nginx container running, while certbot container's state is Exit.

`Attaching to multilaradock_certbot_1
certbot_1  | Requested domain "fake.domain.com" is not a FQDN
certbot_1  | cp: cannot stat '/etc/letsencrypt/archive/"fake.domain.com"/cert1.pem': No such file or directory`

[image]
Nginx configuration my site `site_name.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name site_name.uz www.site_name.uz;
    root /var/www/site/frontend/web;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
        expires 20d; #      20
    }
   # ACME challenge
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt/;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/app_access.log;
}
```

How can we correct this mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the domain name in your docker-compose -file.

Currently your domain name is "fake.domain.com" and it should be fake.domain.com

Comment: Thank you. I'll see now. Then I'll write